# Ajax query string param are being added to standard get request

Tags: ajax, spring, rest, spring-mvc, url

I have an ajax code with parameter like this

```
   var data = {
        attr1: 'attr1',
        attr2: 'attr2',
    }

   jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/report/preview.html',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result){
            jQuery('#report-body').html(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr,a, b){
            console.error(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

The function generates url - `/report/preview.html?attr1=attr1&attr2=attr2`.

I have a display table in jsp which does a full reload every page navigation. My problem is that it also append the parameter i set in ajax call to the url in browser.

The url of display table action is /report/reportHome.html. after the ajax call, when i navigate to another table page, the url becomes /report/reportHome.html?attr1=attr1&attr2=attr2. It appended the ajax param to its parameter. How can i remove these parameters? thanks.

Comment: USE type:POST  instead of GET

Comment: I already did this even before posting this question but with no effect. I have no problem with the ajax call itself but with the page navigation in display table as it appends the ajax parameter. The table requires a full page reload every navigation, but it appends the parameter i set in ajax call..

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a form and POST the information.
2. Use Path variable Ex: /report/attr1/attr2/preview.html
3. Use Session
4. Use some encode/decode

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem! The problem happens because the 'requestURI' attribute of the generated display table of the ajax call adds any tag generated parameters to its value. That is why the request param in the ajax call are being appended automatically as query string in the 'requestURI' attribute of the generated table.

I have resolved this by adding the ajax parameters in the 'excludedParams' attribute of the generated table so they won't be added as query string

So it does not matter what type of request the ajax uses(get or post).